# Remover vírgula com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho uma parte de um blog que é gerenciável.

São as TAGS. Por padrão no sistema, você informa a TAG em um campo específico e ele inclui no blog.

O código está assim:

```
<a href='blablabla' class='tags'>tagSYS, </a>
```

Ou seja, o `tagSYS` é a palavra reservada, o que acontece é que ele inclui sempre uma vírgula, isso está correto quando tem mais de uma palavra.

Mas, quando tem somente uma, ou quando é a última palavra, fica estranho uma "," onde não há continuação.

Tem como tirar isso com jQuery?

Pensei em usar
`$( "tags" ).last()...` Eu não sei a sintaxe para remover 'texto'.

Um exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que você deveria corrigir essa geração, para não acrescentar vírgula no último elemento

Comment: @ErlonCharles é exatamente isso que estou querendo fazer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/DCeU6/

**Opção A**

Pode usar uma expressão regular para tirar só a ultima virgula. Juntei tambem um outro replace para limpar espaços em branco.

```
var string = $('.tags').text();
string = string.replace(' ','').replace(/,+$/, "");
```

O seletor `$`nas expressões regulares indica fim de string.

**Opção B**

Tambem pode simplesmente remover o ultimo caracter da string assim:

```
var string = $('.tags').text();
string = string.replace(' ','');              // limpar espaços em branco
string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1); // usar todos os caracters até ao penúltimo
```

Note que esta opção remove qualquer último caracter. Não somente uma virgula.

---

EDIT: Percebí nos comentários em baixo que cada tag tem seu elemento `<a>` nesse caso tem de usar o pseudo-seletor `:last` ou o `.last()` como você sugeriu na pergunta (e eu não dei atênção)

Assim pode passar uma função para o `.html()` do jQuery e fazer:

```
$('.tags:last').html(function () {
    var string = $(this).text();
    string = string.replace(' ', '').replace(/,+$/, "");
    $(this).text(string)
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/DCeU6/5/

Comment: Seu exemplo funcionou perfeitamente amigo. Mas, para mim, ainda não, aqui está um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/ekth9/

Comment: @FelipeStoker, http://jsfiddle.net/ekth9/1/

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou! :D

Answer (score 3):

```
var noCommas = $('.tags').text().replace(/,/g, ''),
    asANumber = +noCommas;
```

É só usar a função [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Caso queira verificar o último caractere, segue função completa:

```
if (campo.substring(campo.length-1) == ",")
{
    replace
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Mas, com isso, ele vai identificar qual é o último elemento?

Comment: Verifique o edit por favor.